# How to use AutoLayout with UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a problem with the auto layout on an UIScrollView. 
I setup all my constraints exactly like shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnQsFlMGDsI (Until minute 1), but my screen looks like this: [image: a screenshot]

(the orange view is the scroll view and the white one is the content view).

Does the NavigationBar cause this problem, or have I made a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution already. I added the following code in my controller:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```